# Express & Jade - max Block Nesting

Tags: node.js, express, block, pug, nested

i use Express 3x + Jade + bootstrap +..etc

my block/extend structure looks like this

.layout.jade (only head stuff) 
.topNav.jade (only top nav) 
.sideNav.jade (sideNav and control center interface) 
.slidePrem.jade (the actual content)

now i try to res render slidePrem

-> this renders sidenav, topnav, layout (so the "extends" statement is read out of slideprem)

but it wont show any content of slidePrem

so after many many hours of recoding, searching, reintending, etc 
. i rewrote structure to slideprem -> sidenav -> layout

-> this renders slideprem, sidenav, layout

->>> So is there actually a limit of nested blocks?
-> is it editable?
-> or cld u imagine the error somewhere else?

regards Pika

Edit:

```
//slidePrem.jade//

extends ../sideNav
block wall
    #bla (or alert or sth)


//sideNav.jade//

extends topNav
block content
#subHeader
#subHeadNav
#Content //doesnt conflict with "block content" 
    div.container
        div.row
            div.span9
                block wall
            div.span3
                                    // further code



//topNav.jade//

extends layout
block navigation
    div.topnav.....
        div...
            ...
    block content
    #modal


//layout.jade//

doctype 5
html
head
    title= title
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&subset=latin,latin-ext', type='text/css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css', media="screen")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/cCenter.css')

    script(src='/javascripts/jq.js')
    script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/core.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/ajax.js')
body
    block navigation
```

Comment: Could you paste some code ? At least your structure ?

Comment: can you share the error plz.

Comment: there is no error at all - it just ignores the template i render out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to work with **includes** instead of **extends**.

So you can try for your layout.jade :

```
html
  head
  (...)
  body
    block navigation
```

And in your navigation.jade block

```
extends layout

block navigation
  .topnav (div aren't required in jade)
  (...)
  include content
```

Your content.jade only needs then

```
#subHeader
#subHeadNav
#Content //doesnt conflict with "block content" 
 div.container
   div.row
      div.span9
        include wall
      div.span3
```

If that's not clear enough, you can find all the [include documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a13) on the GitHub page of the project.

I hope it'll help.

Comment: There are many situations where deep extends nesting is required so this doesn't answer the question as to whether there is a limit or not.